# Broadcom Bluetooth Chipset BCM2046

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bluetooth, dongle

I have a Mini USB bluetooth dongle, which i have connected to a system running windows 7. It has no buttons on it but when I plug it in it is detected as a keyboard input device. It was originally working but I think what happened was I put the bluetooth device into my pc turned on the radio, unplugged it and forgot and reformatted and now since the radio is set to off it will not detect as bluetooth.

It has happened before when i turned the bluetooth radio off on my windows 7 laptop by right clicking the bluetooth logo in the systray and turning the radio off. I then forgot i did it, and plugged it into a friend's system and attempted to use it to transfer files from my phone. It was detected as a HID input device, but when i brought it back, and plugged it into my laptop, it was detected correctly as a bluetooth dongle and i was able to turn the bluetooth radio back on.

How do i stop the bluetooth dongle from being detected as a HID, and how do i revert it to being detected as a dongle when it does?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Oh and edit your questions tags to include your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always load bluetooth spftware from broadcom. It will detect bluetooth adapter you have and install most recent HCL driver and suppoerting software. In case of BT controller included with keyboard - it is most likely limited in hardware to one single session to make you buy more expensive general-purpose controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what happened.  It sounds like you somehow damaged your bluetooth dongle, but it would surprise me if a bluetooth dongle could be damaged by unplugging it or that you could "reformat" it (unless it has both a flash drive and a bluetooth radio).  I think it is more likely something in your PC that is wrong.  If you had special drivers for your dongle, try to reinstall them.

Comment: well when i download the windows 7 broad-com update it doesn't recognize the dongle and the dongle shows up in device manager as input device and what it USED to show up as was a blue tooth radio but in windows 7 i didn't work because it required the update. but this happened to me once before i plugged in to to a different machine after i turned off the radio and it didn't recognize properly but i was able to take it back to the original machine and turn the radio back on.

Comment: @s32ialx - This may be a stupid question but here goes. `Are you 100% sure it's not the bluetooth dongle of a wireless keyboard?`

Comment: yes i bought it at walmart in Canada for $20 it is designed just for bluetooth connections i know why u ask tho because Microsoft has bluetooth keyboard propitiatory hardware that can ONLY be used with there keyboards

Comment: Is there a bluetooth keyboard anywhere in the vicinity?

Answer (score 0):

To inform everyone I did finally get it fixed what happened was I turned off the radio using the windows drivers on a different computer then the one I had the issues with forgetting I did that because some time had passed since I did that I slipped my mind not to mention I didn't think it would literally keep it off even when plugged in to a new computer, Luckily I still had access to the computer with no changes made to the drivers etc and I reinitialized the dongle and away I went. thanks all for the assistance though I am glad I figured this out I didn't want to get another bt dongle